# JavaScript works locally but not when deployed to webserver

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I'm deploying some code to a website and when I do the JavaScript does not run. I get the error:

> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

The code it is using is

```
@model MVCMasterDetail.DataAccess.cwwoLoadCurrentWorkOrderActualsResult[]

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").show();
    });
    $(".hide-rows").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").hide();
    });
});
</script>

@Html.Partial("MasterDetailMasterPartial")
```

And what calls uses it is:

```
<td colspan="4"> Details<br/><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="grid-toggle">Show-     </a><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="hide-rows">Hide</a></td>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you've forgot to add the essentials...

Comment: Sounds like you are not including jQuery properly.

Comment: double check your requests using firebug, maybe you're not loading the jQuery library

Comment: Are you referencing jQuery in your document

Comment: Your code didn't make it into the question, however we don't actually need to see the javascript, just the `<script src=>` includes.

Comment: Jquery is included, but it acts like it has not been.

Comment: Is it physically there? Is the website set as a Virtual Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery before any other scripts. It sounds like you have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="customScriptThatUsesjQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-x.y.z.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-x.y.z.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="customScriptThatUsesjQuery.js"></script>
```

Check that it appears in your HTML source before any other scripts that use it.

Comment: I've changed it to read:

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".grid-toggle").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").show();
            });
            $(".hide-rows").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
and still have the same error. This is in the head

Comment: Ah, I see. Make sure that `../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js` is a valid path on your webserver. You can use Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to check that the page's resources are being loaded correctly.

Comment: That did it, I just changed the source to the specific file on the webserver. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based off your comment in Ashley Ross's answer, it looks like your trying to add jQuery using a relative path. it also looks like you're using MVC. In MVC, the way you want to reference a file in html is:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
```

Also, it doesn't matter if your script tag goes in the head tag or not. The only difference it makes is loading. By putting it in the head tag, you're telling the browser to download the js file before it begins to load the body, which can be nice, but can also increase page load times. For faster page download, you actually want to put your script tags towards the bottom of your body tag, which defers downloading the js file until after the rest of the page has loaded. This results in faster page load times, but can cause some funky behaviors if you aren't anticipating it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add reference to jquery lib in `<head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Or at the end - http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/